# (Google Speech API) What is frame size?

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

The Google Speech to Text [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) recommends using a 100 ms frame size to minimize latency.

*Any frame size is acceptable. Larger frames are more efficient, but add latency. A 100-millisecond frame size is recommended as a good tradeoff between latency and efficiency.*
-Best Practices

However, what is frame size I do not know.
Is the frame size the same as the AudioBuffer.length?

[AudioBuffer.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/length)

Answer (score 0):

The frames are chunks of `StreamingRecognizeRequest` messages that can contain one of the two fields: `streaming_config` and `audio_content`. The first `StreamingRecognizeRequest`message will ship only the streaming_config, after that all the subsequent messages will ship audio_content.

You can find more details in [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#streamingrecognizerequest) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming-recognition) documentations.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your perfect explanation!

Comment: I'm glad to know it helped. Please accept the answer if you consider valid, for the benefit of community:) Thanks!